# how to make on-screen netbeans preview match runtime

Tags: java, netbeans, look-and-feel

I am trying to get runtime display to match the preview

here is what I am looking at:
http://i236.photobucket.com/albums/ff111/DrivingTibNaked/Screenshot-1-5.png

As you can see the editor does not match runtime.  It shows it the system way when I use the form preview button, but then at runtime I get the weird looking java environment.

I've tried messing with the look and feel settings before the window is created and I cannot get the system look-and-feel to work.   Why all the inconsistancy?  How can I create a good Ubuntu form with netbeans?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
                UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
```